# Locating list elements in an array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. I have a list `indices`.

I want to locate each element of `indices` in `A` and print the corresponding values from `B`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 0,  5],
       [1,6]])

B=np.array([[9.16435586e-05],
       [1.84193464e-14],
       [1.781909182e-5]])

indices= [[0,4],[1,6]]

for i in range(0,len(indices)):
    A=indices[i]
    print(A)
```

The current output is:

```
[0, 4]
[1, 6]
```

The expected output is:

```
[[0,4],[1,6]]
[[9.16435586e-05],[1.781909182e-5]]
```

Comment: Your code never uses `B`. How could you expect to print its values???

Comment: That's right. I don't really know how to refer the order so as to print values from ```B```.

Comment: but `indices= [[0,4],[1,6]]` contains slices of `A`, not indices

Comment: You can call whatever you like. Basically, I want to locate ```[0,4]``` from ```indices``` in ```A``` and print the corresponding value from ```B``` i.e. ```[9.16435586e-05]```. Similarly, for ```[1,6]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
common_index=[x for x,y in enumerate(A) if list(y) in indices]
#[0, 2]
lst=[]

for t in common_index:
    lst.append(list(B[t]))

#output
[[9.16435586e-05], [1.781909182e-05]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to append the ```B``` values?

Answer (score 1):

To generate a list based on index match I would do it like that, you can also modify this based on your use case

```
new_list = []
for i, elem in enumerate(A):
    if list(elem) in indices:
        new_list.append(B[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is good at processing arrays of *numbers* in a vectorized way. Here, you would better use plain Python lists:

```
A = [[ 0,  4],
       [ 0,  5],
       [1,6]]
B = [[9.16435586e-05],
       [1.84193464e-14],
       [1.781909182e-5]]
indices= [[0,4],[1,6]]
print([A[i] for i,v in enumerate(A) if v in indices])
print([B[i] for i,v in enumerate(A) if v in indices])
```

gives as expected:

```
[[0, 4], [1, 6]]
[[9.16435586e-05], [1.781909182e-05]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's where method to achieve this:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 0,  5],
       [1,6]])

B=np.array([[9.16435586e-05],
       [1.84193464e-14],
       [1.781909182e-5]])

indices= [[0,4],[1,6]]

for i in range(0,len(indices)):
    index = np.where(A == i)
    print(index)
    print(A[index])
    print(B[index])
```